# Blowing up something larger than the singular locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that we have a variety $X$, which we know is smooth outside of some subvariety $Z$.  And suppose there is a smooth subvariety $Z \subset W \subset X$ such that the blowup $Bl_W X$ is smooth.

Considering the blowup map $f : Bl_W X \to X$, if we know that the fiber dimension over a general point of $W$ is different from the fiber dimension over a general point of $Z$, [**EDIT** thanks to Mohan] then $X$ is singular somewhere in $Z$.  Are there conditions we can check to determine if the singular locus is all of $Z$?

Comment: If $X$ is indeed smooth, then the blow up along $W$ is smooth and the fiber dimension at all points of $W$ is constant.

Comment: Good point.  Edited the question to fix.